# Compile a library with clang (from LLVM byte code)

Tags: clang, llvm, llvm-clang

I have a library foo in foo.c:

```
int foo() { return 0; }
```

I want to compile to a static object`foo.o`. When I do it directly like the following, this works.

```
clang -c foo.c -o foo.o
```

However, I want to go via the llvm byte code:

```
clang -emit-llvm -c foo.c  # Compile to LLVM byte code
clang foo.bc -o foo.o      # Compile LLVM byte code to native
```

The last command fails with following error message:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.0/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
clang-3.9: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I know that there is no main, which is expected since I compile a library. How to compile that library from LLVM byte code?

Comment: I think you’re adding the `-c` to the wrong line in the LLVM case. What happens if you run `clang foo.bc -c -o foo.o`? Not an answer because I’m not at all sure I’m right; it’s just a guess.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21907504/how-to-compile-shared-lib-with-clang-on-osx

Answer (score 0):

As Daniel H mentions in comment,

the compilation commands should be:

```sh
clang -emit-llvm -c -o foo.bc foo.c
clang -c foo.bc -o foo.o
```

then it is okay to make a library with `foo.o`, I have tested it on clang9.

Hope this helps.