# create dylib file for iOS app development from visual studio c++ project

Tags: c++, ios, visual-studio-2017, dylib, visual-studio-2017-build-tools

I have a Visual Studio C++ project. This project has the functionality for correction the fish-eye images into the original rectangular image files.
I want to use this functionality in my iOS app development by inserting dylib library file.

How can I create it from my C++ project? Is there any guide for this one?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: With the way Apple is, I believe you'll have to compile on a Mac.

Comment: @sweenish, I see. Mac is ready for me. and also, C++ project is ready.
In that case, could you please guide me in more detail?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to compile shared lib with clang on osx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21907504/how-to-compile-shared-lib-with-clang-on-osx)

Comment: That's very helpful for me. But I think there is no exact answer to my question. 
Anyway, really thanks.