# Is it possible to determine (at runtime) if a function has been implemented?

Tags: c++, c, function, runtime, conditional-statements

One of `Objective C`'s primary features is simple [introspection](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Introspection/Introspection.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010810-CH9-SW1).  A typical use of this functionality is the ability to check some method (function), to make sure it indeed exists, before calling it.

Whereas the following code *will* throw an error at runtime (although it *compiles* just fine (`Apple LLVM version 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)`))...

```
@import         Foundation;
@interface      Maybe : NSObject + (void) maybeNot; @end
@implementation Maybe                               @end

int main (){ [Maybe maybeNot]; }
```

By adding one simple condition before the call...

```
if ([Maybe respondsToSelector:@selector(maybeNot)])
```

We can wait till runtime to decide whether or not to call the method.

Is there any way to do this with "standard" `C` (`c11`) or `C++` (`std=c14`)?

i.e....

```
extern void callMeIfYouDare();

int main() { /* if (...) */ callMeIfYouDare(); }
```

I guess I should also mention that I am testing/using this is in a [`Darwin`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darwin_(operating_system)) runtime environment.

Comment: I suppose you could implement your own dynamic function lookup/calling code like Obj-C.

Comment: On which operating system? Standard C don't have any introspection

Comment: If the function doesn't exist, you'll get a linker error. And that's it. There's never any need for your program to do any such checks in runtime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On GNU gcc / Mingw32 / Cygwin you can use [Weak symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_symbol):

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern void __attribute__((weak)) callMeIfYouDare();

void (*callMePtr)() = &callMeIfYouDare;

int main() {
        if (callMePtr) {
                printf("Calling...\n");
                callMePtr();
        } else {
                printf("callMeIfYouDare() unresolved\n");
        }
}
```

Compile and run:

```
$ g++ test_undef.cpp -o test_undef.exe

$ ./test_undef.exe
callMeIfYouDare() unresolved
```

If you link it with library that defines callMeIfYouDare though it will call it. Note that going via the pointer is necessary in Mingw32/Cygwin at least. Placing a direct call callMeIfYouDare() will result in a truncated relocation by default which unless you want to play with linker scripts is unavoidable.

Using Visual Studio, you might be able to get __declspec(selectany) to do the same trick: [GCC style weak linking in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2290587/gcc-style-weak-linking-in-visual-studio)

Update #1: For XCode you can use `__attribute__((weak_import))` instead according to: [Frameworks and Weak Linking](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Concepts/WeakLinking.html)

Update #2: For XCode based on "Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.57) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)" I managed to resolve the issue by compiling with the following command:

```
g++ test_undef.cpp -undefined dynamic_lookup -o test_undef
```

and leaving `__attribute__((weak))` as it is for the other platforms.

Comment: That's a "no go" with `Xcode 7.x`'s bundled tools.  Im instilling the latest `gcc` to see if that does any better (for my platform)...

Comment: What's the Xcode saying? Check this out: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Concepts/WeakLinking.html Apparently instead of __attribute__((weak)) you can use __attribute__((weak_import))

Comment: Even Apple's own example won't compile, _for me_.  A complete, non-functional example project, [can be found here](https://github.com/mralexgray/WeakLinks).

Comment: I'll try this on my mac in the evening.

Comment: Ok, I tested it on my Mac and seemd to have solve the issue by compiling with the following command: `g++ test_undef.cpp -undefined dynamic_lookup -o test_undef` and leaving `__attribute__((weak))` as it is.  Furthermore - the pointer trick is not necessary with my version of XCode - callMeIfYouDare() can be checked and called directly. Please confirm if it works for you.

Comment: YES, that _does seem to work_.  More [info here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695234/what-is-the-deal-with-undefined-symbols-in-a-shared-library-or-dylib), but basically, you need the (`Xcode`) `OTHER_LDFLAGS = -undefined dynamic_lookup`, at which point (even) Apple's code works. [Project updated](https://github.com/mralexgray/WeakLinks) to reflect this solution.

Comment: What else would you like to know to accept this as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

C++ or C don't have introspection. You could add some with your additional layer (look at [Qt metaobject](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/metaobjects.html), or GTK [GObject introspection](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GObjectIntrospection) for examples); you might consider customizing [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) with [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) to get some introspection... (but that would take weeks). You could have some additional script or tool which emits C or C++ code related to your introspection needs ([SWIG](http://www.swig.org/) could be inspirational).

In your particular case, you might want to use [weak symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_symbol) (at least on Linux). Perhaps use the relevant [function attribute](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#Common-Function-Attributes) so code.

```
extern void perhapshere(void) __attribute__((weak));
if (perhapshere) 
   perhapshere();
```

and you might even make that shorter with some macro.

Maybe you just want to load some plugin with [dlopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) and use [dlsym(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlsym.3.html) to find symbols in it (or even in the whole program which you would link with `-rdynamic`, by giving the `NULL` path to `dlopen` and using `dlsym` on the obtained handle); be aware that C++ uses [name mangling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling).

So you might try

```
void*mainhdl = dlopen(NULL, RTLD_NOW);
if (!mainhdl) { fprintf(stderr, "dlopen failed %s\n", dlerror());
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
```

then later:

```
typedef void voidvoidsig_t (void); // the signature of perhapshere
void* ad = dlsym(mainhdl, "perhapshere"); 
if (ad != NULL) {
   voidvoidsig_t* funptr = (voidvoidsig_t*)ad;
   (*funptr)();
}
```

Comment: I still get `Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64` - even after declaring the function `weak` This is originally how I thought it would be done, just don't quite know why it doesn't work. 

Comment: Then show your exact code in the question and explain how you build your program. Last time I used the weak symbol trick it did work on Linux.

Comment: nothing fancy... code is verbatim as above, compiled with `clang src -o exe`

Comment: This could be OS specific. You really should **mention your *exact* code** in *your question*, what OS are you using, **how did you link your program**, etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you can see a function of an object (not pointer) is called in a source code and the code is compiled successfully - then the function does exist and no checking needed.

If a function being called via a pointer then you assume your pointer is of type of the class that has that function. To check whether it's so or not you use casting:

```
auto* p = dynamic_cast<YourClass*>(somepointer);
if (p != nullptr)
  p->execute();
```

Comment: This requires the `YourClass` to have at least one `virtual` member (and preferably have a `virtual` destructor).

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch sounds reasonable. but not sure if dynamic_cast is used for moving up and down of a hierarchy only

Comment: This really doesn't cover the case where symbol is declared but not implemented / linked.