# Why can't this dynamically loaded library access the loading program's global variables?

Tags: c, global-variables, dynamic-linking

First of all, I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933667/accessing-main-program-global-variables-from-a-dlopened-dynamic-library-in-c-on) (<- a link), and it isn't working. I am using OS X.

a.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

int global_var = 0x9262;

int main(void) {
  void *handle = dlopen("libb.so", RTLD_LAZY);
  void (*func)(void);
  char *err;
  if (handle == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", dlerror());
    return 1;
  }
  func = dlsym(handle, "func");
  if ((err = dlerror()) != NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", err);
    return 2;
  }
  global_var = 0x9263;
  func();
  return -dlclose(handle) * 3;
}
```

b.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern int global_var;

void func(void) {
  printf("0x%x\n", global_var);
}
```

Compiling and running:

```
$ gcc -shared -rdynamic -fpic -o liba.so a.c
$ gcc -shared -fpic -o libb.so -L. -la b.c
$ gcc -fpic -o a a.c
$ ./a
0x9262
```

Why doesn't it print `0x9263`? I have tried many combinations of compiler flags, and none of them work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've created two instances of `global_var`.  One is defined in `liba.so`, and that's the one that `b.c` is referencing.

The other is defined in `a`, and that's the one that your `main()` function is referencing.

If you want your main function to reference the variable in `liba.so`, it needs an `extern` declaration of it instead of a definition, and it needs to link against that library itself.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question.
The answer is also interesting.

As caf mentioned in his reply, you have created two definitions of global_var.

To do what you are trying to achieve, you have to make sure that, global_var is resolved from main executable. for that , you will have to create an import file which states that, global_var is imported from main executable. In the import file, you should use #!. for this.

Then use this import file while creating the library.

Also while compiling the main binary, make sure that the global_var variable is exported. use appropriate compiler flags.

On my unix box, i tried this and it works.

```
# cat imp.imp
 #!.

 global_var

cc main.c -bexpall
cc  lib.c -bM:SRE -bnoentry -bI:./imp.imp -bexpall -o libb.so
```

Comment: the # is not coming properly in the post