# Visibility of symbols among sibling .so files

Tags: c, linux, shared-libraries, elf, dlopen

I'm trying to make this OSX code ([golfed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_golf) for ease of discussion) work on Ubuntu Linux.

```
cat >main.c <<EOF
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
void provided_by_main() { puts("Hello main!"); }
int main() {
  void *provider_so, *needer_so;
  (provider_so = dlopen("provider.so", RTLD_NOW)) || printf("Fail %s\n", dlerror()) && (exit(0),0);
  (needer_so = dlopen("needer.so", RTLD_NOW)) || printf("Fail %s\n", dlerror()) && (exit(0),0);
  void (*needer)() = dlsym(needer_so, "needer");
  needer();
}
EOF

cat >needer.c <<EOF
extern void provider();
void needer() { provider(); }
EOF

cat >provider.c <<EOF
#include <stdio.h>
void provider() { puts("Hello provider!"); }
EOF

gcc -shared -o provider.so provider.c
gcc -shared -o needer.so needer.c -dynamic -undefined dynamic_lookup
gcc -o main main.c -ldl
./main
Hello provider!
```

On Linux, via trial and error and StackOverflow, I determined that `needer` cannot refer to anything defined in `main` unless `main` has been linked with `-rdynamic`:

```
gcc -shared -fpic -o provider.so provider.c
gcc -shared -fpic -o needer.so needer.c -Dprovider=provided_by_main
gcc -o main main.c -ldl -rdynamic
./main
Hello main!
```

However, I cannot get `needer` to see anything provided by `provider` even if the entire "chain" is compiled with `-rdynamic`:

```
gcc -shared -fpic -o provider.so provider.c -rdynamic
gcc -shared -fpic -o needer.so needer.c
gcc -o main main.c -ldl -rdynamic
./main
Fail needer.so: undefined symbol: provider
```

So, how do I make this work?

Or, if it's impossible on Linux by design, then *why* is it designed to be impossible?

(OSX equivalent: [Accessing main program global variables from a dlopen()ed dynamic library in C on OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933667/accessing-main-program-global-variables-from-a-dlopened-dynamic-library-in-c-o))

**Real-world bonus complication:** In my actual program, `provider.so` is code-generated at runtime, and the name of the `provider` symbol isn't determined until after `main` has been linked. However, even an answer that involves modifying `main.c` would be a step in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this works on OS X and fails on Linux is that RTLD_GLOBAL is dlopen's default symbol visibility on the former, whereas the latter defaults to RTLD_LOCAL. Use (carefully):

```
dlopen("provider.so", RTLD_NOW | RTLD_GLOBAL);
```

-rdynamic on the other hand only applies to missing library symbols that are defined in the executable, but not anywhere else.

---

```
sed -i 's/RTLD_NOW/RTLD_NOW|RTLD_GLOBAL/' main.c
gcc -shared -fpic -o provider.so provider.c
gcc -shared -fpic -o needer.so needer.c
gcc -o main main.c -ldl
./main
Hello provider!
```

Comment: Thanks! :D  (I've edited your comment to include cut-and-pasteable code.)

Answer (score -1):

The `dlopen` call is failing at run-time, so it can't find or open `provider.so`.  This is from `man dlopen` on OS X and might help:

> dlopen() searches for a compatible Mach-O file in the directories
>   specified  by a set of environment variables and the process's current
>   working directory.   When set, the environment variables must contain
>   a colon-separated list of directory  paths, which can be absolute or
>   relative to the current working directory. The environment  variables
>   are LD_LIBRARY_PATH, DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH, and
>   DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH.  The first  two variables have no default
>   value. The default value of DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH is
>   $HOME/lib;/usr/local/lib;/usr/lib.  dlopen() searches the directories
>   specified in the  environment variables in the order they are listed.

Comment: Sorry, this answer is wrong. Consider deleting it so future visitors don't get needlessly confused.